# PyQt5 обновление окна qtextedit в реальном времени

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть графический интерфейс на PyQt5. В этом окне есть qtextedit - окно для ввода/вывода текста, когда пользователь кликает по кнопке "Получить данные" вызывается функция которая получает данные по COM порту, данных много и они приходят в разные промежутки времени.

Проблема состоит в том, что после того как кликаешь по кнопке "Получить данные" функция вызывается только один раз, и данные которые продолжают дальше лететь в COM порт, они уже не выводятся в qtextedit, т.е. нужно сделать так что бы qtextedit постоянно проверяло есть ли новые данные. Как это сделать к сожалению не знаю.
К сообщения прилаживаю псевдо пример, который выполняет аналогичные действия только с циклом, назв.функции my_func.

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from time import sleep

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = 1
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("example")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 18, 200, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("Получить данные")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 240, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("example", "example"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("example", "Получить данные"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.my_func)
        # Поле вывода текста
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("centralwidget2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 350, 250))

    def my_func(self):  #  Функция имитирует получение динамических данных. Данных приходит много и с задержкой.
        for i in range(1000):
            self.plainTextEdit.insertPlainText(str(i)+'\n') # Выводим полученные данные
            # sleep(1)  # Если закоментировать задердку, то всё ок, если раскоментировать задержку то программа виснет

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А окно не зависает с такой фигней? :) Когда вы работаете с чем-то синхронным в главном потоке (в котором крутится гуи приложения) вы можете невольно замедлить его работу, вызывая зависания. Поэтому работу выполняйте в дополнительном потоке, а из него в главный поток посылайте сообщения

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы окно не подвисало, работу выполняйте в отдельном потоке.

Пример:

```
from time import sleep
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    about_new_log = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            text = str(i) + '\n'

            # Посылаем сигнал
            self.about_new_log.emit(text)

            sleep(1)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = 1
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("example")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 18, 200, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("Получить данные")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 10, 10))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 240, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("example", "example"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("example", "Получить данные"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.my_func)

        # Поле вывода текста
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("centralwidget2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 350, 250))

        self.thread = MyThread()
        # Подключаем сигнал потока к методу plainTextEdit
        self.thread.about_new_log.connect(self.plainTextEdit.insertPlainText)

    def my_func(self):  #  Функция имитирует получение динамических данных. Данных приходит много и с задержкой.
        # Запускаем поток
        self.thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Извините, а можно к моему примеру как-то показать, как потоки разделить?

Comment: @Dima вы уже задавали несколько вопросов, на которые вам были даны ответы, но почему-то ни один ответ не отмечен как правильный ?